# odometry navigation

Tags: navigation, odometry, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to implement the navigation in a two wheeled robot with the ROS navigation-package using Kinect , How can I calculate the odometry if I have the radius, the wheeled distance, the poses and the velocity of the wheels???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67040/odometry-navigation/) by [salime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5267/salime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Odometry can be calculated by estimating "**forward kinematics**" of mobile robot. Here is a link for one such explanation [http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~allen/F11/NOTES/icckinematics.pdf](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Eallen/F11/NOTES/icckinematics.pdf)

Hope this helps...

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5267/salime/) on 2013-07-12**:
Thank you... it helped me a lot, but just one question
Given that vr= velocity of the right wheel, vl=velocity of the left wheel, R=the
signed distance from the ICC to the midpoint between the wheels...

When vr=vl, R becomes infinite and there is no rotation, so how can I manage this situation?

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-07-12**:
When vr=vl, the robot should move straight, as you mentioned there will be no rotation.

**Comment by [salime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5267/salime/) on 2013-07-19**:
So, is it ok for the navigation if I keep receiving nan (not a number) values in the equations, I have tried asigning a really big number when I get nan, but of course in some cases this won't work because of the overflow. Do you know how can I control this part?

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-07-19**:
I am not sure about this, but one thing you can do is not calculate R when difference between vr and vl  is very less.

**Comment by [salime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5267/salime/) on 2013-07-22**:
Thank you for your reply, I did that, the R thing, and now looks like the nan is gone, but the final pose (x,y, theta) keeps getting bigger and bigger when I start moving the robot, even though when I stop moving it.. it keeps getting bigger and bigger in the x, y and theta, and of course these values are not correct for the pose

**Comment by [salime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5267/salime/) on 2013-07-23**:
I have done some tests in the particular case when vl !=0 and vr != 0, incrementing the x, y, ant theta just in these cases, but the results do not look correct either